# Programmatically set a textview based on current local time

Tags: android, date, time, comparison

I would like to set a custom textview based on the 3 different day stage (morning, afternoon, night)

So that:

```
if (morning) {
    mText.setText("it's morning!");
}
```

and the same for afternoon and night. Is that possible?
Thank you

Comment: so what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use that

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String str = sdf.format(new Date());

String[] hr=str.split(":");

int hr1=Integer.parseInt(hr[0]);

if(hr1<12)
{
   mText.setText("it's morning!");
}else if(hr1>12&& hr1<17)
{
 mText.setText("it's afternoon!");
}elseelse if(hr1>17&& hr1<20)
{
 mText.setText("it's evening!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course that's possible. You didn't ask more questions though...

Comment: I didn't add so much code. I know i can do something with Date and now. But how do i make the comparison? using int maybe?

Comment: You can get the milliseconds since epoch from a Date. This is a long value, which means you just normally compare it.

Comment: A quick search yielded `calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` is likely what you want, use logical comparison so if that is < 12, it's morning

Answer (score 1):

> Use this code it will help you
>
> XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relative">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

> Android Code

```
package com.example.dynamic;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       
       
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
       //get current date time with Date()
       Date date = new Date();
      String tim =dateFormat .format(new Date());
      String[] hr=tim.split(":");
      String s1="";

     int hour=Integer.parseInt(hr[0]);
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), hr1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     if(hour<12)
     {
       // mText.setText("it's morning!");
        s1= "it's morning!";
     }else if(hour>12&& hour<17)
     {
      //mText.setText("it's afternoon!");
        s1= "it's afternoon!";
     }
     else if(hour>17&& hour<20)
     {
      //mText.setText("it's evening!");
        s1= "it's evening!"; 
     }
       System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
        RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
        TextView textDynamic = new TextView(this);
        textDynamic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textDynamic.setText(s1);
        textDynamic.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        textDynamic.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textDynamic.setTextScaleX(2);
        textDynamic.setTextSize(20);
        textDynamic.isClickable();
        textDynamic.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        rl.addView(textDynamic);       
    }
       

  }
```